# ES6 play nice.. How to use this.someFunction() inside angular directive without controllerAs?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11, angular-directive

Take for example this Angular directive that works fine in Chrome & Firefox:

```
// using Angular v1.4.8
myApp.directive('myDir', function(){
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'directive/myDir/myDir.html',
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: 'mydir',
      controller: function($scope){
        var thisdir = this;

        // Using ES6 arrow functions
        thisdir.shoutOut = () => {
          console.log("Shouting out!");
        }
      }
   }
});
```

Now on IE11 it throws a syntax arrow because the browser does not recognize arrow functions. However, I can still use:

```
function shoutOut(){
   console.log("Shouting out!");
}
```

But I want to be able to use `var thisdir = this` throughout my directives. For cleaniness of code, I also want to avoid using `$scope` in my directives. Ultimately my directives will depend on eachother in order to create a larger directive/component, which is why i would like to use `var thisdir = this`.

So how can I achieve this while maintaining syntax compatibility with older browsers? If you see a cleaner way to go about this, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
thisdir.shoutOut = () => {
    console.log("Shouting out!");
}
```

by the ES5 equivalent:

```
thisdir.shoutOut = function() {
    console.log("Shouting out!");
};
```

Or use a transpiler like Babel to transform your ES6 code to ES5 code.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly what I was looking for! Didnt realize it was that straightforward.